# VS not finding implementation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have several questions regarding Visual Studio:

two developers using VS2012 and VS2013 are working on the same project but the one with `the lower version studio cannot use ctrl+F12 to find the implementation` of a function.

Those implementations are separated from the interfaces in another library-project.

Second question is strictly concerning VS2013:
two different solutions both are MVC, the first one is version 5.2.2.0 and the other is - 4.0.0.0
in the second project I am able to find a view by using F12 on in the controller (e.g. `return View(model);` or `return View("CustomFormat", model);`)
However I am not able to do it in my first project.

Any information on why it is the way it is or how to fix it, would be appreciated.

TLDR;

**Q1:** Why doesn't `ctrl+F12` work in VS2012 when decoupled implementation from declaration (but it does work in VS2013)

**Q2:** Why doesn't `F12` when pressed on 'View' `return View(model);` find the View itself regarding using 2 different MVC version projects (one is 5 and the other is 4)

Comment: It's still quite unclear what exactly you are doing (on what symbol exactly do you guys press F12, for instance?) but I dare guess that in the first case, VS cannot find a method implementation because you've decoupled the caller from the implementation using an interface, so VS jumps to the interface method definition instead of to the implementation. This is not a bug, it's exactly as it should be (even though it's often annoying having to figure out at compile time what implementation will be used at run time).

Comment: Re: Q1 in your update: What does "it doesn't work" mean exactly? What do you expect to happen, and what does happen, when you press Ctrl+F12?

Comment: It says "Implementation not found" when being invoked on VS2012, however on VS2013 it redirects me to the implementation itself